# Unserialize data and remove item from array and re serialize array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I am trying to update a serialized array that was generated using the php below...

```
// my php and array serialization
$myArray = array( 161 => true, 180 => true );
$myData = serialize($myArray);
setcookie('my_cookie', $myData);
```

I am using jQuery to get this serialised data from my cookie.

```
// remove item click function
$('.remove-item').click( function(e) {

    // get the serialized data
    console.log(Cookies.get('my_cookie'));

});
```

This is my returned serialzed data

```
a:2:{i:161;b:1;i:180;b:1;}
```

I want to be able unserialze this data and remove a item from the array, then serialze the data again and re-set my cookie.

So I would get the value from a data attribute on my `.remove-item` button, and remove this value from the unserialzed array.

It need it work something like this, I just cant figure out how to actually do it. See below my walk through, but this obviously won't actually work.

**jQuery**

```
// remove item click function
$('.remove-item').click( function(e) {

    // get the item id number
    var removeItem = $(this).data('id');

    // 161

    // get the serialized data
    var myData = Cookies.get('my_cookie'));

    // a:2:{i:161;b:1;i:180;b:1;}

    // unserialize data back to an array
    var myArray = unserialize(myData);

    // array(2) { [161]=> bool(true) [180]=> bool(true) }

    // remove 161 from my array
    myArray = $.grep(myArray, function(value) {
        return value != removeItem;
    });

    // array(1) { [180]=> bool(true) }

    // re serialize my array 
    var newData = serialize(myArray);

    // a:1:{i:180;b:1;}

    // re set cookie with new serialized data
    Cookies.set('my_cookie', newData);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="remove-item" data-id="161">Remove Item</button>
```

Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of handling data between the client/server side, rather than using serializing I'd change it to JSON. That way you can just run `JSON.parse(data)` to return your array of data.

**PHP**

```
$myArray = array( 161 => true, 180 => true );
$myData = json_encode($myArray);
setcookie('my_cookie', $myData);
```

**jQuery** -

```
// remove item click function
$('.remove-item').click( function(e) {

    // get the item id number
    var removeItem = $(this).data('id');

    // get the serialized data
    var myData = Cookies.get('my_cookie'));

    // convert cookie string to data
    var myArray = JSON.parse(myData);

    // myArray = {"161":true,"180":true}

    // remove our value
    delete myArray[removeItem];

    // turn the array back to string
    var newData = JSON.stringify(myArray);

    // re set cookie with new serialized data
    Cookies.set('my_cookie', newData);

});
```

That should sort you out :)